# Convert NULL to NOT NULL col on massive SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I got a table that is hundreds of millions of rows. One column, lets call it `ref_id`, is defined as:

```
ref_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL References ref(id)
```

Is there any way to make this column `NOT NULL` and drop the FK constraint?

I have managed to delete the entries with `NULL Ref_id` but when I do

```
ALTER TABLE tbl
ALTER COLUMN ref_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
```

then nothing happens after 8 hours (waiting while its executing)\

Thanks

Comment: I'm surprised.  Changing a column from `NULL` to `NOT NULL` should not require rewriting the data pages, although there might be a verification that requires reading all the data.

Comment: Just curious, did you COMMIT the delete transaction?  In other words, could there be a lock on the table which is blocking your alter statement?

Comment: Is it a typo or did you really specified `NULL` the 2nd time?

Comment: [Why does ALTER COLUMN to NOT NULL cause massive log file growth?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/29522/3690)